# Why doesn't wx graphical modeler Grass gis 7 work properly in Spanish?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

I am working with the wx graphical modeler in grass gis 7.

When I try to use a variable call "archivo" in spanish, wich is "file" in english, it does not work. The variable dont let me choose a file.

But if I change the language to english it work fine. even if having the interface in spanish I use the name type "file" in place of "archivo" it works.

Anyone know why this is happening?

This are some screenshot
This is in spanish
[image]

This in English
[image]

This in Spanglish
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using "archivo" as type of data, not as name. This is why it does not work. Types of data allowed are in the dropdown arrow. HTH

[image]

Comment: That option is given by the program... I don't write "Archivo", I selected in the dropdown arrow when the interface is in Spanish. For now I'm working with the interface in english.